# How to split continuous data into groups?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have two data sets, the first one with discrete data and the second one with continuous data:

```
import numpy as np

# discrete
data1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4,7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]

# continuous
data2 = np.random.normal(size=100)
```

Now I want to calculate frequencies. It's straightforward for data1, since it contains discrete values:

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter(data1)
sum = sum(c.values())
for key,val in c.iteritems():
   print([key,float(val)/sum])
```

How can I do the same for continuous numbers? From theory I know that continuous data must be grouped. Only after this it can be represented as a bar chart. So, how to group the data in python?

Comment: Are you restricted to NumPy, or are you able to use pandas?

Comment: @ajcr: This is just an example. So, if it would be nice to see how to use pandas

Comment: Are you asking for [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts)?

Comment: Have a look at `numpy.histogram` for the continuous data.  Similarly, you can use `numpy.bincount` for the discrete data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). You can use [`numpy.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) to get one of those from your array. You pass a numpy array and the edges of your groups (or *bins*, as they are commonly called) to the function, and it will return a 2-tuple, consisting of the number of elements in each bin and the bin edges. Example from the docs:

```
>>> np.histogram([1, 2, 1], bins=[0, 1, 2, 3])
(array([0, 2, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

@ajrc mentioned pandas in the comments. If you have a pandas `Series` (and you can just create one with `s = pandas.series(data2)`, you can create a histogram by calling [`s.hist()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.hist.html). It will create a histogram with equally-spaced bins over the range of your data (the default number of bins is 10, but you can adjust that by using the `bins` parameter).

Answer (score 7):

For numpy, have a look at [`np.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) for the continuous data and [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html#numpy.bincount) for the discrete data.

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np

data1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
data2 = np.random.normal(size=100)


discrete_counts = np.bincount(data1)
discrete_vals = np.arange(len(discrete_counts))

counts, edges = np.histogram(data2)
```

If you'd like to plot the results, have a look at [`plt.hist`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) and [`plt.bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar).

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
data2 = np.random.normal(size=100)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

counts = np.bincount(data1)
vals = np.arange(len(counts))
axes[0].bar(counts, vals, align='center', color='lightblue')
axes[0].set(title='Discrete Data')

axes[1].hist(data2, color='salmon')
axes[1].set(title='Continuous Data')

for ax in axes:
    ax.margins(0.05)
    ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you're using `pandas`, as @Carsten mentioned, look at the `hist` function to plot the histogram (similar to `plt.hist`).  However, the equivalent of `numpy.histogram` is [`pandas.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html), which is extremely handy when you want the histogram counts (or want to group by a continuous range).